# Replicate array to certain length in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array [1,2,3]

I would like to be able to set its length to 7

and have this [1,2,3,1,2,3,1] as a result.

Anyone?

```
const arr = [1,2,3];

// Something like
arr.resize(7);

console.log(arr); // [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
```

EDIT:
Based on **chevybow** answer below i wrote this functions to serve my needs.

```
// Immutable
Array.prototype.resize = function(size) {
    const array = Array(size);
    for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = this[i%this.length];
    }
    return array;
}

// Mutable
Array.prototype.resize = function(size) {
    const array = this.slice(0);
    this.length = size;
    for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this[i] = array[i%array.length];
    }
}
```

Are those ok? or you think that putting it on the chain is not a good idea, if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modular arithmetic to loop through up to the length of your final array and then use the index to basically loop through and push that onto a new array

Using the current array value % array.length will get you the current position of the array by progressing it in a circular motion

```js
let num = 7;
let array = [1,2,3];
let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
  result.push(array[i%array.length]);
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That is a great approach!

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop would suffice:

```js
function repeat(arr, toLength) {
  let output = [...arr];
  while (output.length < toLength) output = [...output, ...arr];
  return output.slice(0, toLength);
}
console.log(repeat([1, 2, 3], 7));
console.log(repeat([1, 2, 3], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this version:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];

function resize(arr, length) {
  let position = 0;
  return Array.from(Array(length)).reduce((acc, _, i) => {
    return acc.concat(arr[i % arr.length]);
  }, []);
}

console.log(resize(nums, 7));
```